# Entity Framework Core using GroupBy() with Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I want to use `GroupBy()` method dynamically with generic repository pattern.

In example my simple generic repository for `count()`

```
public Task<long> GetCountAsync(Expression<Func<IEntity, bool>> predicate, Func<IGrouping<object, TEntity>> groupBy) 
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = db.Set<TEntity>();

    query = query.Where(predicate);

   //how must i use group by method
   //this give cast error
    query = query.GroupBy(groupBy);

    return await query.AsNoTracking().CountAsync();
 }
```

How can i use `GroupBy()` method with entity framework core in generic repository pattern?

Comment: Where and GroupBy return different types. You cannot assign GroupBy result to query variable

Comment: @pagratios and we can not use groupby() method with predicate? Can we cast it?

Comment: Any update on this? I am stuck on this issue as well

Comment: Any luck so far?